# Unable to reference any mail package assembly

Tags: c#, xamarin, office365, system.net.mail, mailkit

I'm working on a mail service and I can't seem to reference System.Net.Mail or MailKit. I'm left with this error trying download a nuget package for my PCL project reference. What seems to be the alternative way to fix this? I was advised to use Office365 outlook services but I dont know how to use it?

```
    Could not install package 'Mail.dll 3.0.16292.1158'. You are trying to   
    install this package into a project that targets         
    '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7', but the package does not 
    contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with 
    that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Comment: Mail.dll is not MailKit nor System.Net.Mail. That said, MailKit does not support Profile7 (MimeKit does, but that's because it does not need any Socket support). Profile7 does not support sockets so it's *impossible* for any SMTP, POP3, or IMAP library to support Profile7.

Comment: Why are you trying to target PCL? What platforms are you trying to support? Have you considered straight .NET 4.5 or .NET Core? You'll need to target >= .netstandard1.3 to use MailKit, but that's the future of PCL anyway.

Comment: @jstedfast you kinda answered my uncertainties.. We're targeting kiosk/desktop win 10 apps. I wasn't the one that setup the project targets so I wasn't sure why we were using Profile 7. I'll get back to you on that.

Answer (score 0):

A Portable Class Library or `.NETPortable` means that the library depends on just a limited set of functionality from the system that it runs on, in order to make it cross platform compatible.

The packages that you tried to install were not built for that (they need more base functionality) and so they can't be used with your project.

If you need to stay PCL compliant then you could try **[MimeKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MimeKit/)** - purely based on the fact that their page has a section for 'Portable Class Library'; never used it personally.

Comment: is MimeKit alternative for MailKit?

Comment: MimeKit and MailKit are part of the same project. MimeKit is the MIME parser and MailKit is the library that does IMAP, SMTP, and POP3 using MimeKit.

Comment: Oops, then it's not what I had assumed, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all the suggestions above. One thing I might try the next time when I come back here again:

- Open .csproj file;
- Remove the empty line above `</ItemGroup>`;
- Save the file.

I don't know if the removal of the empty line was a problem, but at least the (re)saving of the file worked.